# How to change text dynamically in a qlabel to get next value of the database by a pushbutton?

Tags: c++, sql, qt

I want to change the text in my label by the next value in the database from a pushbutton. I tried the following code, it didn't work-

```
void category::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
QString d;
QSqlQuery qry;
QVariant b=0,s=0;
b = qry.exec("select count id from category");
if(b>=s)
{
    s++;
    qry.prepare("select heading from category");
    qry.exec();
    d=qry.value(0).toString();
    ui->label_2->setText(d);

}}
```

It shows the error:-"invalid operands to binary expression('QVariant' and 'QVariant')" in the if statement-
[error picture(for more understanding)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E4g4.png)

I changed QVariant to int, and it didn't show any error but when i run it doesn't change the text on clicking pushbutton

Comment: What didn't work?  Have you tried to use a debugger to inspect where it failed?

Comment: Always describe what happened when things don't work. An expert will often be able to tell you exactly what went wrong and how to fix it just from the description.

Comment: "select count id from category" correct?    I always write "select count (id) from category"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should check it in this way: "if (qry.exec())". Secondly, you can see what's wrong with this "QString log = qry.lastError().text();"